# Как получить ресурс из другого класса?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Не могу разобраться как часть кода разместить в другом классе и потом получить к нему доступ.

В классе `Resurs` я получаю из файла `string.xml` данные и загружаю их в массив `String[] title`, так же в этом же классе создаю метод `findResurs()`, где загружаю в `List arrImage` картинки, картинок в приложении более четырехсот, здесь для примера только две

```
public class Resurs {
    private Context context;
    List<Person> persons;

    public Resurs(Context context) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        // загружаю в массив
        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titleString);
    } 

    public void findResurs(){ 
        List arrImage = new ArrayList<>(); 
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img1); 
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.img2);}
    }
```

Затем в Активити `MainActivity` подключаюсь к классу

```
Resurs resurs = new Resurs(this);
```

Теперь как можно загрузить данные из `Resurs` в `persons`, другими словами получить из `Resurs title` и `arrImage1`

```
int length = title.length;
persons = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    persons.add(new Person(i, title[i]  arrImage1.get(i)));
```

Класс Person

```
public class Person {

long id;
String title;
int photoId;

// пустой конструктор
public Person() {
}

// конструктор с переменными

public Person(long id, String title,  int photoId1) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.photoId = photoId;
}}
```

Comment: К вопросу не относится, но хранение ссылки на активити чревато утечками памяти.

Comment: Да вроде ничего секретного в приложении нет да данных пользователя в приложении нет. Я не знаю, а что может утеч с приложение

Comment: Называйте классы правильно, в английском языке есть слово Resource, но никак не Resurs

Comment: Речь не про утечку конфиденциальной информации, а про memory leak.

Comment: Так может стоит просто сделать `title` и `arrImage` полями класса `Resurs`, и создать геттеры?

Comment: Vladimir Parfenov  Я пробовал, но Resources res = context.getResources() работает только в конструкторе,  а arrImage  если просто отдельно вывести выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил класс `Resources`(такое название правильнее `Resurs`) считать набором инструментов для загрузки данных из ресурсов, а метод получения персон реализовать статичным. Например так:

```
public class Resources {

    public static Person[] loadPersons(Context ctx){
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        // загружаю в массив
        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titleString);
        // статичное определение списка картинок
        int[] images = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, ..., R.drawable.imgN};

        if(title.lenght != images.lenght)
            // количество картинок не соответствует количеству имён
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        Person[] persons = new Person[title.lenght];
        for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
            persons.add(new Person(i, title[i],  images.get(i)));

        return persons;
    }
}
```

Что касается *кэширования* - считаю, что это нужно оставить на усмотрение вызывающего кода. Не стоит перегружать класс `Resources` ещё и этой ответственностью.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то.
Я так понял вопрос лучше разбить на несколько частей и опубликовать отдельно, а то сейчас наверно не очень понятно, что именно нужно